# Namespace is not attached in field names of tab included in CQ

Tags: xml, namespaces, aem

While working on CQ 5.4, I developed a component that had dialog with two tabs containing the same fields, and I was duplicating code which made it difficult to maintain, so I decided to separate the tabs into a new .xml and include them with `cqinclude`.

I read [here](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/cqinclude-namespace.html) and [here](http://aemtuts.com/how-to-create-reusable-dialog-xml/) that it is possible to define a namespace and that it would be used to prefix the field name; but when I try, no prefix seems to be included, and the values in the fields are "duplicated" (I guess they are saved once for each tab).

This is a simplified version of my code:

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
          height="500"
          width="600">
  <items
         jcr:primaryType="cq:TabPanel"
         activeTab="{Long}0">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
      <image0-tab
                  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                  path="/apps/acme/components/mycomponent/dialogTileTab.cqinclude.namespace.image0.infinity.json"
                  xtype="cqinclude"/>
      <image1-tab
                  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                  path="/apps/acme/components/mycomponent/dialogTileTab.cqinclude.namespace.image1.infinity.json"
                  xtype="cqinclude"/>
    </items>
  </items>
</jcr:root>
```

dialogTileTab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
          title="Tile"
          xtype="panel">
  <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
    <buttontitle
                 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                 defaultValue="Click Me"
                 fieldLabel="Button Text"
                 name="./button"
                 xtype="textfield"/>
    <titlecolor
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                defaultValue="blue"
                fieldLabel="Button Color"
                name="./color"
                type="select"
                xtype="selection">
      <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <o0
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Red"
            value="red"/>
        <o1
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Green"
            value="green"/>
        <o2
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Cadillac Blue"
            value="blue"/>
      </options>
    </titlecolor>
  </items>
</jcr:root>
```

With that, I can see the dialog and the tabs correctly, but the problem comes when saving the information because the fields in both tabs have the same names and instead of being saved separately, they are concatenated and saved together. For example, if I have a text field and in tab1 I write "text1" and in tab2 I write "text2", when I save an reopen, the value in both tabs will be "text1,text2".

So far I have only made changes in the dialog.xml and the new tab xml. Did I miss something or some setting in these or other files? Do I need to include any bundles? could it be a general/server setting or is it something that can be done just at the component level?

Comment: This is not an OOTB feature and requires the ACS AEM Commons Package to be installed in the instance. Can you confirm if it is already installed?

Comment: @rakhi4110 You are correct: ACS AEM Commons package is not installed, and that's why it is not working fine. If you could put that as an answer (with a link to where to find/install the package if possible) I'll mark it as the valid answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an OOTB feature and requires the ACS AEM Commons Package to be installed in the instance.

Also below is an excerpt from the **How to use** section of [this link](http://aemtuts.com/how-to-create-reusable-dialog-xml/) which you have mentioned in the question.

> First of all, you need to have the acs aem commons package installed
>   (CQInclude Namespace is available since version 1.10.2).

The appropriate release based on the version of AEM you are currently running can be obtained [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/releases).